# Access win 10 HDD with Win 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, nas

I have 2 laptops. One is loaded with Win 10 and the other with Win 7.
The Win 10 laptop's screen died, and I don't have access to an external monitor. I would like to copy some files from the win 10 HDD before sending it for repair.

I tried connecting the Win 10 drive as an external (1) USB and (2) eSATA drive (using Orico caddy) to the Win 7 laptop, but I was not able to access the drive.
I also tried connecting it as an external (1) USB and (2) eSATA drive to a Synology NAS and although I could see the drive, I was not able to access any files.

One further idea that occurred to me was to try to boot the Win 7 laptop to command prompt from the Win 10 drive connected as an external USB drive but I am fearful this approach may damage the Win 10 installation.

Appreciate some guidance to access the Win 10 HDD.
TIA.

Comment: Windows 7 should absolutely be able to access the files of the HDD unless it’s encrypted.  I assume that is not the case

Comment: Are you sure that the laptop's screen died ? I guess then you could send it for repair without the HDD then..I did that once.

Comment: Use minitool partition wizard or disk management on your windows 7 laptop and check if the win 10 HDD is displayed as "GPT Protective Partition".

Comment: @Ramhound: Not encrypted

Comment: @Elmo: With USB connection to laptop, in Win 7 Disk Management the HDD shows up as "Not Initialized". It offers 2 style options to initialize viz. MBR and GPT. I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @user3835567 If its disk capacity is shown, that means your Windows operating system has recognized this disk, but its partition is lost or MBR is corrupted due to some reasons.

Comment: @user3835567 You will need to rebuild the MBR, Strongly suggest you to go through this article:
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/disk-unknown-not-initialized.html
And if that didn't work then this:
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/disk-unknown-not-initialized.html

Comment: @Elmo: Will it be ok to rebuild the MBR under Win 7 for a Win 10 disk? Won't that adversely affect the existing Win 10 installation on the drive?

Comment: For fear of losing data I did not do anything to the drive. Instead I ordered a new screen online and replaced the faulty one. I am now back to having a working Win 10 laptop.